# Online beta testing, how to record viewed content

Tags: html, selenium, mechanicalturk

I'm setting up a beta testing/QA system to direct Mechanical Turk workers to client web pages for review.

The Turk worker sees a questionnaire HTML page on Mechanical Turk. It contains:

- a target URL for them to visit
- a question form about this content of the URL

The problem is that target URLs for some clients contain dynamic content. No two Turk workers end up seeing the same page. However, we really need to be able to associate the Turker's answers to the questions with the actual content that they saw.

Because only a single page is required, my hope was that we could download the client page, save it on S3 and direct the Turker there. However, relative paths in the HTML break. If I take the URL:

```
http://www.example.com/abc/def.html
```

grab the content, inject :

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/abc">
```

save the result to amazon S3, and point the MTurk worker there, then this helps solves some problems. However, much of the page (for reasons I'm not sure about) fail to render properly.

Are there any other tricks I can employ? (Framing? ... )

Comment: Why not ask the worker to save the page themselves and upload it to MTurk? That way they can visit the original page and you still know what they saw.

Comment: That's a good thought -- we may go down this this route if needed. Its second best to a technical solution because: i) it takes more time for the Turk worker, ii) it adds error space e.g. what if they complete 10 such tasks, can you always trust them to save and upload the page correctly (and not attached the saved page for question 6 by accident)?